# Visual Studio solution requires an old version of MFC. How can I get it to accept the latest version?

Tags: visual-studio

I just uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2022.  When I tried to build the solution I'm working on, every project failed because I did not have the MSVC tools folder named 14.35.32215.  When I checked, I saw that I had a folder named 14.36.32532. Is there some way to set up my projects so that the latest MSVC tools will be acceptable, no matter what version that is?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what setting this version refers to, because this exact version is not set anywhere AFAIK. Can you show the compiler settings part of the vcxproj file?